# Alternatives For DefaultDict

Tags: python, defaultdict, python-2.4

Unfortunately, for me, I need to make a script backward compatible w/Python 2.4, and `defaultdict` doesn't exist in 2.4 version.

What can be an alternative for it?

The data structure for a given key is a list of:

```
[{'red': (12, 1, 12), 'white': (30, 2, 60), 'blue': (8, 1, 4), 'orange': (9, 4, 8), 'black': (10, 12, 4)}]
```

EDIT: 
Adding usage info. First I build the default dict with:

```
defDict[key1].append(... ...)
```

Then it's passed to several methods for key:val(list) lookups and key deletion.

Specifically for deletion:

```
        if len(defDict[key1][0]) == 0:
            del defDict[key1]
```

EDIT: error on NoneType

```
        print "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        print defDict[key]
        print "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
        if len(defDict[key][0]) == 0:
            #del defDict[key]
```

Error:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
None
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
if len(defDict[key][0]) == 0:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I think the error comes from `key`:

```
        print "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        print defDict[key]
        print "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

Output:

```
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       None
       yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Comment: Depends what you're doing with it. `get`, `setdefault`, or explicit `in` checks are the usual alternatives.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you. I've edited the question. First I build the dict, and then it's called through some methods.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @niMaMoh the desired output is key-Val dictionary where each Val is a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement your own `defaultdict` in a pretty straightforward manner.

```
def defaultdict(default_type):
    class DefaultDict(dict):
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            if key not in self:
                dict.__setitem__(self, key, default_type())
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    return DefaultDict()


list_dict = defaultdict(list)
list_dict['a'].append(1)
print list_dict # {'a': [1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict(list)` is just a nice bit of sugar for

```
if key not in d:
   d[key] = []
d[key].append(...)
```

Comment: Can you store a list as dictionary value?

Comment: Indeed.  That's what the `defaultdict(list)` is doing under the hood anyway.

Comment: @Simply_me A simpler version of this answer is `d.setdefault(key, []).append(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to write a backport for `defaultdict`:

```
class defaultdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kw):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            result = self.default_factory()
            self[key] = result
            return result
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does this support deletion of items?

Comment: it behaves in most ways exactly like the `defaultdict` of python 2.6.

Comment: @Simply_me: why not?

Comment: I get the following error: `return dict.__getitem__(key) ......TypeError: descriptor '__getitem__' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'`